# Python big values in one byte array

Tags: python, arrays, integer, byte

Can someone help me how to put these int values in one byte array?
I would like to have one array, which I can send over a socket.

```
lat=int(4065538)
lon=int(1446611)
velo=int(33)
```

I can put every value to one byte stream with

```
lat = lat.to_bytes(3, 'big')
lon = lon.to_bytes(3, 'big')
velo = velo.to_bytes(2, 'big')
```

but I don't know how to bring them to one.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

First create an empty `bytearray`, then concat to it

```
data = bytearray()

data += lat.to_bytes(3, 'big')
data += lon.to_bytes(3, 'big')
data += velo.to_bytes(2, 'big')
```

Comment: You can add bytes objects together: `data = lat + lon + velo`